# How to Classify unbalanced classes with Random Forest avoiding overfitting

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I'm stuck in a Data Science problem.
I'm trying to predict some future classes using Random forest.
My features are categorical and numerical.
My classes are unbalanced.
When I run my fitting, the score seems very good but the cross validation awful.
My model must overfit.

Here is my code:

```
features_cat = ["area", "country", "id", "company", "unit"]
features_num = ["year", "week"]
classes = ["type"]

print("Data",len(data_forest))
print(data_forest["type"].value_counts(normalize=True))

X_cat = pd.get_dummies(data_forest[features_cat])
print("Cat features dummies",len(X_cat))
X_num = data_forest[features_num]
X = pd.concat([X_cat,X_num],axis=1)
X.index = range(1,len(X) + 1)

y = data_forest[classes].values.ravel()

test_size = 0.2
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)

forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, n_jobs=4, oob_score=True, max_features="log2", criterion="entropy")
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

score = forest.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Score on Random Test Sample:",score)    

X_BC = X[y!="A"]
y_BC = y[y!="A"]

score = forest.score(X_BC, y_BC)
print("Score on only Bs, Cs rows of all dataset:",score)
```

Here is the output:

```
Data 768296    
A    0.845970
B    0.098916
C    0.055114
Name: type, dtype: float64
Cat features dummies 725
Score on Random Test Sample: 0.961434335546
Score on only Bs, Cs rows of all dataset: 0.959194193052
```

So far I feel happy with the model...
But when I try to predict future dates, it gives mostly the same outcome.

I check cross-validation:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, n_jobs=4, oob_score=True, max_features="log2", criterion="entropy")
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs=4)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

And it gives me poor results...

```
Accuracy: 0.55 (+/- 0.57)
```

What do I miss ?

Comment: What is your class label distribution?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change (or remove) `random_state`? `train_test_split` is not stratified by default, so it could be that your classifier is always just predicting the most common class `A`, and your test split with that partition just contains `A`'s.